# Getting 500 Internal Server Error on my cpanel hosting?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have been trying to download a zip file from my cpanel server but I was getting first 403 forbidden error so I added `.htaccess` with the following code as :
`Require all granted` so for the time my 403 forbidden error was solved but now I am getting 500 Internal Server Error..!

Here is link to the directory where I am getting error please as : 
http://huntedhunter.com/backups/

And I want to download this file as : 
http://huntedhunter.com/backups/backup_hunter.zip

so getting the 500 Internal server error on file downloading..!

So if you people can please help me.

Comment: Just removed the `Required all granted` from `.htaccess` and again now i am getting 403 forbidden error..!

Comment: check the file permission on `backup_hunter.zip`

Comment: @pushpraj : Thanks for pointing out.yes I changed it is accessable now..! post it as answer and I will select your answer please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, the issue is with the file permission for `backup_hunter.zip`

so make sure the file permissions are set accordingly

an example from [File Permissions Tutorial](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/file_permissions.htm)

[image: sample]

image  from the linked tutorial, read the same for more info